# How to properly do regex expression in Fn::Sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In a cloudformation template JSON file,  I am trying to specify a metricfilter for multiple LogGroupNames using RegEx like the samples below.

I did look at the java.util.regex.Pattern documentation which AWS says is what it bases its regex syntax on but that did not help.

```
"LogGroupName": {
                "Fn::Sub": "/aws/lambda/${Vpc}-lambdaname\\*"
```

or

```
"Fn::Sub": "/aws/lambda/${Vpc}-lambdaname\\[A-Z0-9]+"
```

But I continue to get this error message:  ...'failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [.-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+ (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException...'

What is the proper regex syntax that I need or is there another way to specify the multiple log groups?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fn::Sub` doesn't do regular expressions and what you're after is also not a regular expression, it's a wildcard, but then looking at `AWS::Logs::MetricFilter` documentation I don't think it supports wildcard expressions. You need to specify exact log group reference so you'll have to create a separate `MetricFilter` for each log group name (if there indeed are many). Maybe what you mean is all the log streams in the log group? In that case you are fine without the `/*` suffix because the filter applies to all streams in the group. For a lambda function the log group is in the form `/aws/lambda/<FunctionName>` so in your case `"Fn::Sub": "/aws/lambda/${Vpc}-lambdaname"` and you're done.

The exact error you were having was saying that `\` (back-slash) is not a valid part of a log group name. When you say `\\*` it becomes `\*`. You probably meant `/*`, but as explained above you don't need it.

Fn::Sub:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html

AWS::Logs::MetricFilter:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-metricfilter.html

Comment: Thanks jbasko.  I'm trying to setup metric for every log group that starts with specific string, not logstream.  We have several deployments and new log groups get created so I was hoping specifying just a regex would be an easy solution.

Comment: Yes, then you need a separate `MetricFilter` for each. What I'd do is define it next to where I define each `LogGroup` (which for me personally is next to every `Lambda::Function`; it's not necessary, but I do it because then I can control log expiration; unfortunately you can't do it after log groups have already been created outside of CloudFormation's watchful eye) and if there is some pattern that you don't want to be updating in all the places, I'd use a Parameter for that with value looked up from SSM Parameter Store.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a separate MetricFilter because new log groups keep getting created after deployments and the log group name is generated with a dynamic id(I don't know how to capture in my cloudformation template) at the end of the name.   Example:  '/aws/lambda/<lamba name>-FVU22IVJVGP

Comment: If you specify `FunctionName` for your lambdas then they won't have random names. If you create the LogGroup yourself then you're in control of it. And you can reference the generated lambda's name with !Ref. Here's my typical log group: LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${Function}
      RetentionInDays: 30

Comment: Thanks jbasko.  I went ahead and metricfilter for each.